'client' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046) Error -- bun RPC
server/app.ts
export const app = new Hono();

const appRoute = app.basePath("/api").route("/user", userRoutes)

export type AppType = typeof appRoute

client/App.tsx
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { hc } from "hono/client"
import { type AppType } from "../../server/app"

const client = hc<AppType>("/");

function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchTotal = async () => {
            const resp = await client.api.user.$get() // client' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)
            // ... 

        }
        fetchTotal()
    }, [])

    return (
        // ...
    )
}

export default App

In my vite react application, I'm simply trying to access client.api.user.$get(), however I get the error of client being unknown.
If I were to modify my basePath:
.basePath("/api")
    .get("/", c => {
        return c.json({ message: "It will only see this" })
    })
    .route("/user", userRoutes)

This time, it is going to recognize client.api.$get(), but still client.api.user.$get() will not be recognized.

It possibly an error about route() but I couldn't find a solution.
tsconfig.json --> compilerOptions strict: true in both server and client.

